# How to write a Do-While in LIMS

Tags: winlims

I have been working with Labware LIMS attempting to get my do loop to work. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```
X = 1

Do (SQR (x) < 5 While

X = X + 1

Msgbox(X)

loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is considered a do-while loop. I am assuming your issue is the 2nd line as it should be `Do While`. Supplied below is what I mean.

```
X = 1

Do While (SQR (X) < 5
    X = X + 1
    Msgbox(X)
loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Brad you lost the closing bracket.

```
X = 1

Do While (SQR (X) < 5)

X = X + 1

Msgbox(X)
loop
```